# How to print all values of a multi-value field, except the first?

Tags: theming

Suppose that in a Twig template, I want to print the first value of a multi-value field, then something else, and finally all other values of the same field. Is there a way to do that?

I know how to get the first value of the field, but I don't know how to exclude that first value from the place where I'm printing all other values.

This is what I tried, but doesn't work:

```
{# print first field value #}
{{ content.field_foo.0 }}
{# print something else #}
<hr>
{# print remaining field values #}
{{ content.field_foo|without(0) }}
```

Alternatives for the last line that didn't work either:

```
{{ content.field_foo|without('0') }}
{{ content.field_foo|without('field_foo.0') }}
```

Looking at the code in `twig_without()`, I would expect `{{ content.field_foo|without(0) }}` to work, but instead the entire field disappears.

Comment: Try to use slice filter. Like this:   {% set rows = rows|slice(1) %}. 
So basically just create new variable and remove one element from previous array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [field preprocessing](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.6.x) this while loop which fills the field items doesn't get started if the first delta is removed:

```
  $delta = 0;
  while (!empty($element[$delta])) {
    $variables['items'][$delta]['content'] = $element[$delta];
    $delta++;
  }
```

So if you bypass the field template to print the `0` delta do the same with the other deltas:

```
{# print first field value #}
{{ content.field_foo.0 }}
{# print something else #}
<hr>
{# print remaining field values #}
{% for key, item in content.field_foo if key > 0  %}
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, and extra kudos for figuring out where exactly field preprocessing says "no" ;-) It must be noted that there is a downside to this solution: you lose the field wrapping div in the process. (I tried an alternative method to avoid that: `{%  set remaining_foo = content.field_foo|merge({0: []}) %} {{ remaining_foo }}` but that didn't work.)