# How do I hide an empty field if my custom field formatter removes all items?

Tags: 8

I have a custom field formatter (in Drupal 8) that displays a list of taxonomy terms on a node. Some terms are not meant to be displayed, so the field formatter removes them from the items list.

Occasionally, all items are removed -- yet the HTML elements that wrap the field are still rendered. How do I hide the field completely when all items are removed?

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

I have a field with machine name field_tags that is an entity reference to multiple taxonomy terms.

To render this field, I wrote a custom formatter as a field formatter plugin in a custom module. The code is stored in the standard location in mymodule/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/TermListFormatter.php

My class extends EntityReferenceFormatterBase.

In my class, my viewElements() method strips out some items as needed and sometimes returns an empty array if no items should be rendered.

```
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = [];

    // Loop through each of the terms in this field.
    foreach ($this->getEntitiesToView($items, $langcode) as $delta => $entity) {
      $label = $entity->label();

      // ONLY show taxonomy terms that begin with "Test".
      if (mb_substr($label, 0, 5) === 'Test') {
        $options = [
          'query' => [
            'tags' => [$entity->id()],
          ],
        ];

        // Output terms as links to /test?tags[]={tid}
        $elements[$delta] = [
          '#type' => 'link',
          '#title' => $label,
          '#url' => Url::fromRoute('view.test.page_1'),
          '#options' => $options,
        ];

        if (!empty($items[$delta]->_attributes)) {
          $elements[$delta]['#options'] += ['attributes' => []];
          $elements[$delta]['#options']['attributes'] += $items[$delta]->_attributes;
          // Unset field item attributes since they have been included in the
          // formatter output and shouldn't be rendered in the field template.
          unset($items[$delta]->_attributes);
        }

        $elements[$delta]['#cache']['tags'] = $entity->getCacheTags();
      }
    }

    // This will be an empty array if there were no terms beginning with "Test"
    return $elements;
  }
```

When all the terms are stripped out, the field wrapper elements are still output as follows:

```
<span class="views-field views-field-field-tags">
  <span class="field-content"></span>
</span>
```

How do I stop these elements from appearing when there are no terms to show?

Comment: How did you build the custom formatter? Twig template? You can use conditions to print output only if the output isn't empty.

Comment: I built the custom formatter as a field formatter plugin in a custom module. The viewElements() method strips out some items as needed and sometimes returns an empty array if no items should be rendered.

Comment: You should add such information to your question, probably even with code snippets, your template, an example of the output you get when your fields are emptied, and what output you intend to have instead. This would enable us to give you a fast and to the point answer for your issue instead of having to highlight all possible places where you can influence rendered output (which I'd consider too broad for Drupal Answers).

Comment: I'm confused, too. Drupal hides the field wrapper for empty fields automatically.

Comment: Given your edit, the wrappers added to your output result from the Views module (compare the `views-field views-field-field-tags` classes). Did you try locating this view and altering it by checking the "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR/Hide if empty", and/or "STYLE SETTINGS" or "REWRITE RESULTS" to remove the wrappers entirely?

Comment: @MarioSteinitz you are correct, the issue was that I needed to take the additional step of modifying the View and setting No Results Behavior to "Hide if empty". I'm embarrassed that I overlooked that. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal adds the field wrapper only if the result returned by viewElements() contains at least one renderable child.

*FormatterBase::view():*

```
  public function view(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode = NULL) {
    ...
    $elements = $this->viewElements($items, $langcode);

    // If there are actual renderable children, use #theme => field, otherwise,
    // let access cacheability metadata pass through for correct bubbling.
    if (Element::children($elements)) {
      $entity = $items->getEntity();
      $entity_type = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
      $field_name = $this->fieldDefinition->getName();
      $info = [
        '#theme' => 'field',
        '#title' => $this->fieldDefinition->getLabel(),
        '#label_display' => $this->label,
        '#view_mode' => $this->viewMode,
        '#language' => $items->getLangcode(),
        '#field_name' => $field_name,
        '#field_type' => $this->fieldDefinition->getType(),
        '#field_translatable' => $this->fieldDefinition->isTranslatable(),
        '#entity_type' => $entity_type,
        '#bundle' => $entity->bundle(),
        '#object' => $entity,
        '#items' => $items,
        '#formatter' => $this->getPluginId(),
        '#is_multiple' => $this->fieldDefinition->getFieldStorageDefinition()->isMultiple(),
      ];

      $elements = array_merge($info, $elements);
    }

    return $elements;
  }
```

This means for the question if the field formatter removes all items the field is hidden.

However, field formatter and field preprocessing handle empty fields differently. If you only remove the first field item it is possible that the condition for an empty field has different results. See [How to print all values of a multi-value field, except the first?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/276141/how-to-print-all-values-of-a-multi-value-field-except-the-first)