# Render array only working with numeric keys

Tags: 8

I have a [FieldFormatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-0) that outputs a DIV, a table and attaches a JS library.

Normally in Drupal (e.g. [Form API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2117411)) it's possible to label the render array keys however you like? Weirdly in this case, only numbering them seems to work.

If it's a typo, I'm not spotting it, and there are no errors in the log.

Are there differences in how FieldFormatter rendering works?

**Working numeric keys:**

```
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {

    // various logic ...

    $build = [];

    $build[0] = [
      // placeholder div for the YouTube player
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => [
        'id' => ['youtube-timecode-player'],
      ],
    ];

    // various logic ...

    // attach our timecode.js javascript make the video ID available
    $build[0]['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/youtube_timecode';
    $build[0]['#attached']['drupalSettings']['mymodule']['video_id'] = $video_id;

    $build[1] = [
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#caption' => $this->t('Questions'),
      '#header' => [$this->t('Time'), $this->t('Question')],
      '#rows' => $timecodes
    ];

    return $build;
  }
```

**Non-working text keys (no output and no errors):**

(I've changed `0` to `video` and `1` to `timecode_list`)

```
public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {

    // various logic ...

    $build = [];

    $build['video'] = [
        // placeholder div for the YouTube player
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => [
            'id' => ['youtube-timecode-player'],
        ],
    ];

    // various logic ...

    // attach our timecode.js javascript make the video ID available
    $build['video']['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/youtube_timecode';
    $build['video']['#attached']['drupalSettings']['mymodule']['video_id'] = $video_id;

    $build['timecode_list'] = [
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#caption' => $this->t('Questions'),
        '#header' => [$this->t('Time'), $this->t('Question')],
        '#rows' => $timecodes
    ];

    return $build;

}
```

Comment: Is the table also not outputted with textual keys, or only the video (and container?)?

Comment: @Jaypan sorry not sure I understand you right, but the table I'm calling 'timecode_list' and I don't believe I've got a mix of numeric and text keys.

Comment: I mean, is nothing at all outputted, or are you getting any output at all (from the render array, not the rest of the page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of [FormatterInterface::viewElements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FormatterInterface.php/function/FormatterInterface%3A%3AviewElements/8.7.x) is defined as:

> **Return value**
>
> *array* A renderable array for $items, as an array of child elements keyed by consecutive numeric indexes starting from 0.

The theming layer can't handle other arrays for field values, see  [How to print all values of a multi-value field, except the first?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/276141/how-to-print-all-values-of-a-multi-value-field-except-the-first)